# Find another polynomial with the same roots as a polynomial with radical coefficients

Tags: polynomials, radicals

If  $\sqrt{7}(x^3 - 1) - \sqrt{5}(x^3 - x) + 1 = 0$ is an expression, how would you get a similar expression with the same roots as the one above but without irrational coefficients? I tried bringing it over like $\sqrt{7}(x^3 - 1)  + 1 = \sqrt{5}(x^3 - x)$ and squaring it and doing other step but I keep on getting stuck. Any advice? 
Edit: This is what I have so far, I continued simplifying, but on wolfram, it was expressed as having different roots so I just stopped there .
$$\sqrt{7}(x^3 - 1)  + 1 = \sqrt{5}(x^3 - x)$$
$$7(x^3 - 1)^2  + 2\sqrt{7}(x^3 - 1)  + 1 = 5(x^3 - x)^2$$
$$2\sqrt{7}(x^3 - 1) = 5(x^3 - x)^2 - 7(x^3 - 1)^2  -1$$
$$28(x^3 - 1)^2 = (5(x^3 - x)^2 - 7(x^3 - 1)^2  -1)^2$$

Comment: Starting with $$\sqrt{7}(x^3-1)+1=\sqrt{5}(x^3-x)$$Square both sides to get$$2\sqrt{7}(x^3-1)=-2x^6-10x^4+14x^3+5x^2-8$$Then square again. The resulting polynomial will be a degree of $12$. Is this really what you want?

Comment: yeahh thats what i tried doing. i eventually got $(5(x^3-x)^2-7(x^3-1)^2-1)^2 - 25(7)(x^3-1)^2$ but when I plugged it into wolfram, there appeared to be distinct roots.

Comment: @kuhe: If you want rational coefficients, you will have to accept extraneous solutions (i.e., roots which don't satisfy the original equation). That's just the nature of the game.

Comment: As @quasi says, it’s the nature of the game, and the reason for this is that algebraically, $\sqrt7$ and $-\sqrt7$ behave identically. Similarly, $\sqrt5$ and $-\sqrt5$.

Comment: At least this OP beat their classmates [to](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2169700/11619) [it](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2169845/11619) :-)