# Find another polynomial with integer coefficients with the same root as this one: $(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)x^3 + \sqrt2x -\sqrt3 + 1$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, roots, irrational-numbers

Basically it says given that s is a root of this polynomial: $(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)x^3 + \sqrt2x -\sqrt3 + 1$, find another polynomial with integer coefficients that has the same root s as well.
I'm super stuck and am unsure on how to approach this problem.
I attempted to square some stuff but it didn't really work out.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Another polynomial equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169700/another-polynomial-equation) and essentially the same as [Find another polynomial with the same roots as a polynomial with radical coefficients](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169542/find-another-polynomial-with-the-same-roots-as-a-polynomial-with-radical-coeffic), both asked in the past few hours and answered already.

Comment: A good catch @dxiv! Not surprisingly the askers are from the same smallish geographical area :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why, let's just move all $\sqrt3$'s to the right:
$$\sqrt2(x-x^3) + 1 = \sqrt3(x^3+1)$$
Now let's square it.
$$2(x-x^3)^2 + 2\sqrt2(x-x^3) + 1 = 3(x^3+1)^2$$
Now move all $\sqrt2$'s to one side.
$$ 2\sqrt2(x-x^3) = 3(x^3+1)^2-2(x-x^3)^2-1$$
Now square it again, and you'll have your polynomial with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P_0(x)$ be your polynomial, and $P_1(x)$, $P_2(x)$, $P_3(x)$ the polynomials obtained by

1. substituting $-\sqrt{2}$ for $\sqrt{2}$,
2. substituting $-\sqrt{3}$ for $\sqrt{3}$,
3. doing both substitutions.

Then the product of these, when expanded out, is a polynomial with integer coefficients.